# Is Comcast blocking my SSH on a high port?

Tags: networking, ssh, troubleshooting

I am having trouble getting SSH to work. I am using a non-standard port (9876). I verified my server's IP address both by using an external whatismyip type site, and by using `curl ifconfig.me`, both give the same result.

If I do this from the server:

```
ssh -p 9876 localhost
```

it works.

If I do this:

```
ssh -p 9876 127.0.0.1
```

it also works.

But, if I do this:

```
ssh -p 9876 143.76.123.94
```

I get the error "Connection refused". (Note that the example ip given above is changed from the real address.) If I try to connect from a remote machine on a different network I get the error "network is unreachable", even though I can ping it from the same remote machine.

The only reason I can think for this behavior is that COMCAST is looking inside the packet, seeing that it is an inbound SSH attempt and then automatically impersonating a server refusing the request. Is this what is happening? Are there alternative explanations?

### Additional Notes

Note that I can ping the address in question, so if I can ping it, then it is "reachable" right? How is it, that it is reachable to ping and not to ssh or telnet?

Comment: If you are attempting to connect to yourself using your public ip address that isn't going to work unless you forward traffic on that port to your local intranet address.  I can assure you Comcast isn't blocking your traffic.

Comment: Why would this not work? If I try the command from a different machine on a different public network I get the response "network is unreachable".

Comment: Sounds like you have not forward the traffic on the port to the server as to why that's how your NAT is currently setup

Comment: Ok, so that would mean COMCAST is blocking me, and they must be looking inside the packet, otherwise how would they know it is SSH traffic and not HTTP traffic (which I receive fine on the server machine).

Comment: Comcast isn't not blocking the traffic the http traffic is on another port which is likely being forwarded to your server

Comment: HTTP packets come to a client on random ports. Why would those random ports be forwarded and 9876 not be forwarded?

Comment: @TylerDurden because the client initiated the connection to the server first, and the router recorded the communication in its memory, that way when a response came back the router knows that the traffic goes to which computer on the network.

Comment: Leaving a breadcrumb for myself and anyone else that may run into this.  I had my OBi202 VoIP phone adapter in bridge mode in front of my router.  This was causing all incoming ports to be blocked even though I'd forwarded them correctly on my router.  Apparently the OBi202 doesn't pass them through.  I ended up putting my OBi202 back behind my router to fix the problem, though I will likely have slightly worse VoIP QoS as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are rumors of COMCAST blocking inbound connections by "stateful packet inspection" I found that I was able to connect my machine from outside and that originally I was being blocked by my router which I thought was bridge, but actually was running a NAT. For the benefit of people who may have similar problems details below...

My situation was that I had plugged the connection from the cable modem into an Airport Express which was acting as a hub for the connection to the Linux box running the SSH server. I had thought that the Airport was in bridge mode (ie passing all traffic through), but actually it was in NAT mode which blocks all inbound traffic.

To solve the problem I made an exception on the Airport. First I had to make a dedicated DHCP filter for the server which hardcodes the server's MAC address to an internal IP address of my choosing, then I had to open port 9876 (the port I am using for SSH) on the NAT and point it to the IP address I picked for the server. After that it worked.